# How to align vertical bars in plotly Python with respect to x ticks?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to use Plotly Python to get a graph like this:
[image: left Riemann sum]

This is the code I arrived to:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

fig = go.Figure()

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 50)
y = np.sin(x)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, name='sin(x)', showlegend=True))

a = 0.6
b = 2.0
x_fill = np.linspace(a, b, 50)
y_fill = np.sin(x_fill)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x_fill, y=y_fill, fill='tozeroy', line=dict(width=0), showlegend=False))
n = 4
x_rect = np.linspace(a, b, n)[:-1]
y_rect = np.sin(x_rect)

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x_rect, y=y_rect, showlegend=False))
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(tickmode='array', tickvals=[a,b], ticktext=['$a$', '$b$']))

fig.show()
```

But this is what I get:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend using [`shapes`](https://plotly.com/python/shapes) instead of a bar chart. It *does* mean you need to create the polygons manually, but it gives you much more intuitive control over the widths and heights of the bars. It'll also pave the way for you to be able to implement the trapezoid rule for definite integral approximations, if you're so inclined.

### Solution

Using `dx = (b - a) / n`, you can calculate the left-most x-axis locations for all the rectangles. Adding `dx` to those left anchors gives you the right anchors (the width of each rectangle is `dx`).

Finding the tops of the bars comes down to evaluating `f` at either the left anchor, the right anchor, or at the midpoint.

From there, you generate a `List[dict]` of shape dictionaries, which you can pass directly to `update_layout()` as `shapes`.

```py
from typing import List


def make_shapes(*, f: callable, a: float, b: float, n: int, mode: str) -> List[dict]:
    rect_params = dict(type="rect",
                       xref="x",
                       yref="y",
                       line_width=1,
                       line_color="#00ff96",
                       fillcolor="#00cc96",
                       opacity=0.5)

    dx = (b - a) / n
    x_left = np.array([a + i*dx for i in range(n)])
    x_right = x_left + dx

    if mode == "right":
        y_top = f(x_right)
    elif mode == "left":
        y_top = f(x_left)
    else:
        y_top = f(x_left + dx/2)

    shapes = []
    for x0, x1, y in zip(x_left, x_right, y_top):
        shape = dict(x0=x0, x1=x1, y0=0, y1=y)
        shapes.append({**rect_params, **shape})
    return shapes
```

### Usage

```py
shapes = make_shapes(f=np.sin, a=0.6, b=2, n=4, mode="mid")
fig.update_layout(shapes=shapes)
```

### Examples

For the mid-point rule,

```py
shapes = make_shapes(f=np.sin, a=0.6, b=2, n=4, mode="mid")
```

[image]

For right-anchored Riemann sum,

```py
shapes = make_shapes(f=np.sin, a=0.6, b=2, n=4, mode="right")
```

For left-anchored,

[image]

```py
shapes = make_shapes(f=np.sin, a=0.6, b=2, n=4, mode="left")
```

[image]

This solution also accommodates any `n > 0`:

```py
shapes = make_shapes(f=np.sin, a=0.6, b=2, n=15, mode="mid")
```

[image]

An example showing bars below the x-axis, for good measure:

```py
def f(x):
    return -np.cos(x)

a = 0.7
b = 2.5
n = 10

shapes = make_shapes(f=f, a=a, b=b, n=n, mode="mid")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This solves part of my problem. Now I need to make each bar not centered around the x points, but to the left (or to the right) or each x point

Comment: That won't be as easy if you're set on sticking with bar charts, as the width of each bar is determined in a way that isn't conducive to these types of plots (bar chars are for histograms and other frequency/counting data). I strongly recommend using shapes.

Comment: @OsvaldoCarvalho see my updated answer.

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to help me. Following your advice I abandoned bar charts and used shapes, but as I would need to draw trapezoids (as you anticipated), so I used shapes by scatter traces. I made an interactive widget to use in my quadrature classes.

Comment: Glad I could help! Wait till you get to Gaussian quadrature, it's awesome :D